# cp: cannot stat a file that certainly exists! (cp: no such file or directory)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cp

I've got a directory with a few .tiffs and for each of them I need to copy a file with the same name (but different extension) from another directory to this one.
Here is the bash script I've made for this (I run it on the dir containing the .tiffs):

```
GT_PATH="~/source/";
for j in *.tiff; do
        cp "$GT_PATH""${j%.tiff}".gt.txt .;
done;
```

However, this is what I get when I run it on a testing dir containing exclusively a file named test.tiff:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘~/source/test.gt.txt’: No such file or directory
```

Now comes the thing that is a little messed up: when I manually run `cp ~/source/test.gt.txt .` , the file gets successfully copied!

What am I doing wrong?! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compare the output of `echo ~` with `echo "~"` and think about how you're quoting things in your script.

Comment: Single or double quotes prevent expansion of `~`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot!!!I changed the ~for /home/user/. However, I'm wondering if there is some way of using the tilde in the variable GT_PATH...